# Android maximum shared library size

Tags: android, memory-management, shared-libraries

I am trying to port some Linux code to Android. I realized that the code would involve several   jni referenced .so shared libraries well over 20 mb in size.

I want to know if there is a maximum size for each .so?

Also, is there a total maximum size for the .so files which my app can have, since .so files are actually memory mapped?

I googled this and found virtually nothing, so a resource describing this would be quite helpful

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no limitation in the size of .so file. I have seen several Android applications where a shared library over 20MB is used.

However, in Android, there is a limition on the NUMBER of .so files loaded in your process. The limit is usually set to 128. Refer to http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/bionic/linker/linker.cpp#286.

The exact number may vary depending on device manufacturers since they often change the constant. You may think the number is quite big enough, but please note that there are many built-in shared libraries loaded in your process even though you do not load any shared library of your own.

I cannot tell you that the 20 shared libraries will or will not exceed the limit. It's device dependent. If you are worried, you may merge those 20 libraries into a single huge library file.

Comment: That link pretty much answers much of my question, though I was more concerned with the size of the .so rather than their number. Thanks Jiyong.

Answer (score 1):

It was a limit on the number of shared libraries of Android's dynamic linker.
But I found the limit is removed recently since 4.3.
In 4.2.2, there is a SO_MAX, see [note of linker.cpp in 4.2.2](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/bionic/linker/linker.cpp#63).
But in 4.3, SO_MAX is removed, see [note of linker.cpp in 4.3](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/bionic/linker/linker.cpp#59).